# OnMessageReceived no response at all on Firebase Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have been finding the problem all around the internet why my emulator in Android Studio didn't receive notification from either my PHP backend_API or from Firebase console but most of them doesn't solve my problem. There are lots of questions about Firebase not receiving notification while on foreground/background. But my problem is `onMessageReceived` not being called at all, I didn't even have once received any response or notification successfully in any situation from Firebase but I am 100% sure I can get the token from Firebase.

I am able to get success response from PHP backend. But once again, never ever have any notification from Firebase!!!

```
{"multicast_id":5857046882374247095,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1490047410456686%14ffa3cf14ffa3cf"}]}
```

I have tested around probably more than 50 times either on foreground or background with various method. I tried few others tutorial as well and they just couldn't work on me. I have tested the `onMessageReceived` with breakpoint, observing Network status(0 kb/s flat = no response) on Android Monitors, searching around the web. No Luck!!!
The code I used is basically 100% similar from the Tutorial I get somewhere on Youtube and his Android emulator did receive notification but not mine with the same code. Can anybody help me please? It took me 3 days but still to no avail.


FirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

    private static final String TAG = "succcess";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        Log.i(TAG, title);

        showNotification(title, body);
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String body) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }


}
```

FirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public final class FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver() {
    }

    public void onReceive(Context var1, Intent var2) {
        if(this.isOrderedBroadcast()) {
            this.setResultCode(500);
        }

        var2.setComponent((ComponentName)null);
        var2.setPackage(var1.getPackageName());
        if(VERSION.SDK_INT <= 18) {
            var2.removeCategory(var1.getPackageName());
        }

        String var3 = var2.getStringExtra("gcm.rawData64");
        if(var3 != null) {
            var2.putExtra("rawData", Base64.decode(var3, 0));
            var2.removeExtra("gcm.rawData64");
        }

        String var4 = null;
        String var5 = var2.getStringExtra("from");
        if(!"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(var2.getAction()) && !"google.com/iid".equals(var5) && !"gcm.googleapis.com/refresh".equals(var5)) {
            if("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(var2.getAction())) {
                var4 = "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT";
            } else {
                Log.d("FirebaseInstanceId", "Unexpected intent");
            }
        } else {
            var4 = "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT";
        }

        int var6 = -1;
        if(var4 != null) {
            var6 = this.zza(var1, var4, var2);
        }

        if(this.isOrderedBroadcast()) {
            this.setResultCode(var6);
        }

    }

    public int zza(Context var1, String var2, Intent var3) {
        return zzg.zzabT().zzb(var1, var2, var3);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.firebasepushnotification23">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

App Level Gradel

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.firebasepushnotification23"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

PHP Server Script 1

```
<?php
include "con.php";

$message = array("title" => "Title", "body" => "body");

function fetchFirebaseTokenUsers($message, $connect) {       
   $query = "SELECT token FROM notification";
   $fcmRegIds = array();
   if($query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {         
      while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        array_push($fcmRegIds, $query_row['token']);
      }
   }

   if(isset($fcmRegIds)) {
      foreach ($fcmRegIds as $key => $token) {
         $pushStatus = sendPushNotification($token, $message);
      }
   }
}

function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

   ignore_user_abort();
   ob_start();

   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

   $fields = array(
     'to' => $registration_ids,
     'data' => $message,
   );

   define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'Key');

   $headers = array(
      'Authorization:key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
   );      

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if($result === false)
      die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
   ob_flush();
}


echo $return = fetchFirebaseTokenUsers($message, $connect);

?>
```

PHP Server Script 2

```
<?php
include "con.php";

function send_notification ($tokens, $message, $messagebody)
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'notification' => $message,
             'data' => $messagebody
            );
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key = Key',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;

     }


    $sql = "select token from notification";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $tokens = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$tokens[] = $row['token'];      }
    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
    $message = array("title" => "Title", "body" => "body");
    $messagebody = array("title" => "Title", "body" => "body");

    $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message, $messagebody);
    echo $message_status;

?>
```

Comment: Hi Vickson. In the future, please always keep your *Server Key* a secret. :) With that said, is it the same case if you try using Topics? Is the behavior just with an emulator or have you also tested it on an actual device?

Comment: @AL. Thanks for your reminder. Yes, I have tried the topic as well but it doesn't work as well. I am able to get the topic appeared in Firebase console after subscribing a topic using FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribe() method but I didn't receive any notification at all by sending notification from Firebase with topic. I have no actual device to test, I only test it on Android Studio Emulator. API 16, API 23 and API 24. Never have once successful. :(

Comment: Hi. That's strange. If even topics doesn't work, it's either there is something amiss in the code for receiving the message or a mix up in the tokens. As much as possible, do test it out on actual device too.

Comment: There's also a possibility that the network you're using is blocking the notifications.

Comment: Oh God @AL. thanks for the answer and reminder, my university wifi totally blocked the ability of my Android Emulator to receive notification from Firebase. It just worked fine after using other wifi network.

Comment: Cool. I'll add in a more decent answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

When working with FCM using your University/Company network, you should refer to the note seen in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#http-request):

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with FCM in order for your Firebase Cloud Messaging client apps to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. FCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. FCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

Or simply make use of your own connection that doesn't block FCM.